# Mule JIRA Copy Attachment and Move it to new Issue

Tags: mule, jira

I am trying to look up for a solution on copy Attachments from One Defect to Another.

I tried to use following Approach but get Attachments is returning as 
type of `com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteAttachment` and I don't see any `StringBuffer` or any Object in this which actually has base64 encoded object which holds Attachment itself.

http://mulesoft.github.io/jira-connector/java/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/beans/RemoteAttachment.html

add Attachments doesn't accept this DataType. http://mulesoft.github.io/jira-connector/mule/jira-config.html#add-base64-encoded-attachments-to-issue

How can I successfully upload Attachments here from one defect to another one?

```
    <flow name="jira-attachments-POC">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/attachments" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <jira:get-attachments-from-issue config-ref="Jira" issueKey="MRT-75" doc:name="Jira"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="attachementsPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="attachementsPayload"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="issueAttachmentNames" value="#[payload[0].attachmentNames]" doc:name="issueAttachmentNames"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="fileAttachmentsArray" value="*"  doc:name="Session Variable fileAttachments"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="fileName" value="#[payload[0].filename]" doc:name="fileName"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="fileId" value="#[payload[0].id]" doc:name="fileId"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="requestPath" value="secure/attachment/#[sessionVars.fileId]/#[sessionVars.fileName]" doc:name="requestPath"/> 
    <component doc:name="Java" class="JIRAAttachmentObjectTransformer"/>
    <jira:add-base64-encoded-attachments-to-issue config-ref="Jira" issueKey="MRT-655" doc:name="Jira">
        <jira:file-names ref="#[sessionVars.fileNamesArray]"/>
        <jira:base64-encoded-attachment-data ref="#[sessionVars.fileAttachmentsArray]"/>
    </jira:add-base64-encoded-attachments-to-issue>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="{payload=#[payload]}"/>
</flow>
```

Transformer Code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class JIRAAttachmentObjectTransformer implements org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(JIRAAttachmentObjectTransformer.class);


    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();
        String reqPath = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("requestPath", PropertyScope.SESSION);
        System.out.println("RequestPath:->"+reqPath);
        try{
            URL fileConnectPath = new URL("http://xxxx.com:8443/"+reqPath);
            URLConnection uc = fileConnectPath.openConnection();

            String userpass = "xxxxx" + ":" + "xxxxx";
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

            uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

            //URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
            //myURLConnection.connect();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    uc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            String byteArrayStr= new String(Base64.encodeBase64(inputLine.getBytes()));
            String strArray[] = new String[1];
            strArray[0] = byteArrayStr;
            eventContext.getMessage().setProperty("fileAttachmentsArray", strArray, PropertyScope.SESSION);
            String fileName = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("fileName", PropertyScope.SESSION);
            String fileNamesArray[] = new String[1];
            fileNamesArray[0]= fileName;
            eventContext.getMessage().setProperty("fileNamesArray",  fileNamesArray , PropertyScope.SESSION);           
            System.out.println("Successfully Added to message.");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

What's the Payload type to setup for

Following ones are errors i am getting right now..

> RequestPath:->secure/attachment/160026/2015-04-03
>   12_03_17-Clipboard.png  java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of
>   file from server  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:772)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:769)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1324)
>   at
>   JIRAAttachmentObjectTransformer.onCall(JIRAAttachmentObjectTransformer.java:38)
>   at
>   org.mule.model.resolvers.CallableEntryPointResolver.invoke(CallableEntryPointResolver.java:46)
>   at
>   org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:36)
>   at
>   org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:339)
>   at
>   org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:82)
>   at
>   org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.doInvoke(AbstractJavaComponent.java:73)
>   at
>   org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:125)
>   at
>   org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:59)
>   at
>   org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1.process(AbstractComponent.java:241)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>   at
>   org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
>   at
>   org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69)
>   at
>   org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50)
>   at
>   org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69)
>   at
>   org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22)
>   at
>   org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>   at
>   org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61)
>   at
>   org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.process(AbstractComponent.java:159)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>   at
>   org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
>   at
>   org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>   at
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>   at

Comment: Does anyone has idea on this ???!!

Comment: Please look this and assist me[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325441/editing-the-pdf-in-mule-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by implemented following approach.

Mule Flow to Move Attachment from One Defect to Another one.

Followed these steps to Add HTTPS install Certificate in my Local Java Environment so i can use https:// specific JIRA URL

http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html

```
 <flow name="jira-attachments-POC">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/attachments" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <jira:get-attachments-from-issue config-ref="Jira" issueKey="#[message.inboundProperties.sourceIssueId]" doc:name="Jira"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="attachementsPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="attachementsPayload"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <set-session-variable variableName="issueAttachmentNames" value="#[payload.attachmentNames]" doc:name="issueAttachmentNames"/>
            <set-session-variable variableName="fileAttachmentsArray" value="*" doc:name="Session Variable fileAttachments"/>
            <set-session-variable variableName="fileName" value="#[payload.filename]" doc:name="fileName"/>
            <set-session-variable variableName="fileSize" value="#[payload.filesize]" doc:name="fileSize"/>
            <set-session-variable variableName="fileId" value="#[payload.id]" doc:name="fileId"/>
            <set-session-variable variableName="srcIssueKey" value="#[message.inboundProperties.sourceIssueId]" doc:name="srcIssueKey"/>
            <set-session-variable variableName="destIssueKey" value="#[message.inboundProperties.targetIssueId]" doc:name="destIssueKey"/>
            <set-session-variable variableName="uploadAttachementBaseURL" value="https://www.jiraurl.com:8443/rest/api/2/" doc:name="uploadAttachementBaseURL"/>
            <set-session-variable variableName="readAttachmentBaseURL" value="https://www.jirawebsite.com/secure/attachment/" doc:name="readAttachmentBaseURL"/>
            <component class="JIRAAttachmentObjectTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>
        </foreach>
        <set-payload value="{&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Sucessfully Attachments Migrated.&quot;}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </flow>
```

> Java Code to copy Attachment and Move to Another Defect.

```
        import java.io.File; import java.io.IOException;

        import org.apache.http.HttpEntity; import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse; import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet; import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost; import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder; import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody; import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient; import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients; import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils; import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext; import org.mule.api.MuleMessage; import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope; import org.slf4j.Logger; import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

        import de.schlichtherle.io.FileOutputStream;


        public class JIRAAttachmentObjectTransformer implements org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable {   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory            .getLogger(JIRAAttachmentObjectTransformer.class);


            @Override   public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {      MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();

                String userName = "xxx";        String password = "xxxxxx";

                String sourceBaseURL = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("readAttachmentBaseURL", PropertyScope.SESSION);       String sourceIssueFileId = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("fileId", PropertyScope.SESSION);      String sourceIssueKey = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("srcIssueKey", PropertyScope.SESSION);        String sourceFileName = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("fileName", PropertyScope.SESSION);

                if(             ( sourceIssueFileId != null || sourceIssueKey.trim().length() > 0 ) &&              ( sourceFileName != null || sourceFileName.trim().length() > 0 )            )       {           String targetIssueKey = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("destIssueKey", PropertyScope.SESSION);           String targetBaseURL = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("uploadAttachementBaseURL", PropertyScope.SESSION);

                    String targetURL = targetBaseURL+"issue/"+sourceIssueKey+"/attachments";            String sourceURL = sourceBaseURL+ sourceIssueFileId +"/" ;


                    String auth = new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64((userName+":"+password).getBytes()));

                    File targetFileName = getAttachmentFromIssue( sourceURL , sourceFileName  , auth);
                    System.out.println("Get Attachment Status:->" + targetFileName.toString() );

                    boolean status = addAttachmentToIssue(targetBaseURL, auth, targetIssueKey, targetFileName);
                    System.out.println("Upload file to JIRA #" + targetIssueKey + " Status "+  status);         }else{          System.out.println("No Attachments Found to Migrate Ticket" );      

}
                return message;     

}

            private File getAttachmentFromIssue(String contentURI, String fullfilename, String auth) throws IOException {

                CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();       File fileName = null;       

    try {           HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(contentURI);          logger.info("Source URI:->"+contentURI);            httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getURI());            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

                    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();          logger.info("Get Attachment:->" + fullfilename +"::Http Response code:->"+ status );            if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {

                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        if (entity.isStreaming()) {
                            byte data[] = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
                            fileName = new File(fullfilename);
                            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                            fout.write(data);
                            fout.close();
                        }
                        logger.info("Successfully file Copied.");           }       } finally {             
         httpclient.close();        
    }       
         return fileName;   

    }       

    private boolean addAttachmentToIssue(String baseJiraURL, String auth, String issueKey, File fileName) throws IOException{
                CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(baseJiraURL+"issue/"+issueKey+"/attachments");         logger.info("Target URL:->"+baseJiraURL+"issue/"+issueKey+"/attachments");

                httppost.setHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
                httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+auth);
                FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(fileName);
                HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart("file", fileBody).build();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                String mess = "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine();
                logger.info(mess);

                CloseableHttpResponse response;

                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    logger.info("JIRA Ticket ID:"+issueKey+"::HttResponse code:->" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                } finally {
                    httpclient.close();
                }

                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
                } 

    }
```